# Uploaded images are not saving in targeted path in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload

I am just trying to upload and save images in my `public/images` folder, I am getting the details of file by `req.files`, after that I am getting this type of `Error: EXDEV, rename 'c:\Users\abdul\AppData\Local\Temp\3348-qiy7kl.jpg'`

here is my `stuff`

```
 app.post('/upload',function(req,res){
    var tmp_path = req.files.file.path;
    var target_path = './public/images/' + req.files.file.originalFilename;
    fs.rename(tmp_path, target_path, function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        fs.unlink(tmp_path, function() {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.send('File uploaded to: ' + target_path + ' - ' + req.files.file.size + ' bytes');
        });
    });
    })
};
```

Can any body give any suggestion or give me any reference so that I can handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
    console.log("File Name " + req.files.file.name);
    console.log("File Path " + req.files.file.path);

    fs.readFile(req.files.file.path, function (err, data) {
        var newPath = "public/images/" + req.files.file.originalFilename;
        console.log(newPath);
        /// write file to uploads/fullsize folder
        fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function (err) {
            /// let's see it
        });
```